# Django: Add value in template_tag

Tags: django

I am using django-qr-code. Just adding `{{ attendee.ticket_code }}` generates {{ attendee.ticket_code }} what I didn't intend.

Can you tell me how I get the value of `{{ attendee.ticket_code }}` in there?

```
{% qr_from_text "{{ attendee.ticket_code }}" size="M" %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% qr_from_text attendee.ticket_code size="M" %}
```